# What benefit to get functions provide in the context of Angular 4 Components?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component, getter-setter

I am curious what the difference between these two functions would be in Angular 4:

```
get currentIndex(): number {
  return `Current Index is ${this.index}`;
}

public currentIndex(): number {
  return `Current Index is ${this.index}`;
}
```

Do they do exactly the same thing? If so when would they do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're pretty much the same, except that functions/methods tend to imply a calculation. So when you're just accessing data (like the index in this case), a function can look odd or seem like overkill.

Using a getter is kind of the best of both worlds. It looks like simple data access - `currentIndex` versus `currentIndex()` - while allowing you to add logic later if you need to do something like a calculation.

Technically they are different though, and you can use the [TypeScript PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20index%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20currentIndexGetter()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60Current%20Index%20is%20%24%7Bthis.index%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20currentIndexMethod()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60Current%20Index%20is%20%24%7Bthis.index%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) to see how they compile down to different code.

Answer (score 2):

`getter/setter` is related to property more than methods so it 's better to compare `getter/setter` to normal property.

and invoking `getter/setter` is the same like any normal property, implement only `getter` mean read only property and implement only `setter` mean write only property.

getter and setter add extra layer to interact directly with property for example

```
class Person {
 private _age:number;
 public get age() {
   //... do something 
   retutn this._age; 
 }

 public set age(value) {
   if (value >0){
    this._age = value
   }
 }
}
```

form the example above we prevent assaign invalid value for age.

in angular if we want to display a getter in teplate for age for example  like this `{{age}}` but if age is an function will be like this `{{age()}}`

as I mention before it 's better to think about `getter/setter` as property more than method

from your example

```
get currentIndex(): number {
  return `Current Index is ${this.index}`;
}
```

this getter above may give the value from service or calculated value of form another property and will look like normal property

[setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) , [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)